# How to dynamically require momentjs locale

Tags: javascript, express, locale, momentjs

Hi Im using expressjs for a backend service in which in need to set the locale for momentjs based on the user browser locale. Im looking for any strategies on how to load the `moment/locale/{locale-file based}` based on expressjs `request.acceptsLanguages`.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: There's documentation on how to do it in NodeJS (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-nodejs/) - does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a `.locale()` function after parsing correct language from request (but you have send a language header at least)

```
const moment = require('moment');
const language = getLanguageFromRequest(req); // or whatever logic you like
moment.locale(language);
```

but maybe it is better idea to handle it in browser, not in a backend.